# Angular viewchild: name by variable

Tags: angular

I have an angular component that calls another component by using a template.
I pass this `ng-template` a `name`.

```
<div>
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="outlet" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{name:'a'}">
      </ng-container>
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="outlet" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{name:'b'}">
      </ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #outlet let-name="name">
  <my-other-component #a></my-other-component>
  <!-- <my-other-component #{{name}}></my-other-component> -->
  <!--  Lots of other HTML -->
</ng-template>
```

But now, in my main component, I would like to have a reference to the first instance of `MyOtherComponent` only. So I could define a reference to it in the typescript file.

```
@ViewChild('a') component: MyOhterComponent;
```

but there are now two instances named as such. I would like only the first instance to be named 'a' (the name is provided).

It is possible to do something like this? (I know te code below does create a reference to it)

```
<my-other-component #{{name}}>
```

So in short. **Is it possible to give a component a name using a variable** and/or condition?

Comment: why you can't name one component `#a` and another `#b`?

Comment: I am using a template, such that it can be reused within the HTML file